# Stop Repeating Alarm in OnReceive which is set in Activity

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to stop or cancel the repeating alarm in onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver which is set in the activity. Where should I call the cancel() method, how can I get the instance of alarmManager in OnReceive method of BroadCastReceiver.

Below is the code snippet

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

setContentView(R.layout.main);

Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);       

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1234567, intent, 0);  

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE)

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (i * 1000), 60*1000, pendingIntent);

}
```

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

static int id;

```
@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

// Vibrate the mobile phone

Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context
                .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

vibrator.vibrate(2000);

id=id+1;

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "A new notification", System.currentTimeMillis());

// Hide the notification after its selected

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Repeat.class);

PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent1,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "This is the title",
                "Notified", activity);

notification.number += 1;


notificationManager.notify(id, notification);




 String as = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1234567, intent, 0);  

    AlarmManager amg = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(as);

    amg.cancel(sender); 


}

}
```

Comment: how to pass alarm object to receiver in order to cancel the alarm

Comment: Long time has passed , but did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to cancel your alarm you can use the following code. (I have not tested this but I do a similar thing to cancel a NotificationService)

```
    String as = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
    AlarmManager amg = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(as);
    PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent1, 0);
    amg.cancel(myIntent);
```

Comment: I made the change which u told, but not able to stop the alarm ,U can the see the code for reference.

Comment: You need to pass the PendingIntent from the Alarm not the PendingIntent from the Notification.

Comment: but the alarms pending Intent is present in activity how can i get it in OnReceive

Comment: Check my edited answer. You have to make that PendingIntent a variable that can be accessed throughout your Activity

Comment: James onReceive is method in BroadCastReceiver not in the same Activity class

Comment: Oh, my bad, try recreating the same PendingIntent in your onRecieve method. Updated Code

Comment: i have made the changes and tried same result not able to stop the alarm . check the updated code for reference

Comment: Try "this" instead of "context" in your onReceive PendingIntent

Comment: "this" cannot be used in BroadcastReceivers James we need to use "context" only.